# Jenkins can't clone my project from git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have set up my Jenkins-on Windows 7- for the first time, everything should be correct, I'm able to clone my git repository through command-line, but when I create a new job in Jenkins, the first step is to clone the Git repo, but it fails. See my Jenkins console log:

```
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https ://xxxxxxxxx/repository 
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
```

I have put the timeout to 50 as well, after 50 min same error.

Here you can see my git setting in Jenkins:

[image: Git settings]

[image: source code management settings]

```
All Log:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Started by user kimo
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Android-AppBuild-Test
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https ://tec.sdm.com/pk/mybestshop/git/repository.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https ://tec.sdm.com/pk/mybestshop/git/repository.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.username kimo # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\git756353511056031456.credentials\" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https ://tec.sdm.com/pk/mybestshop/git/repository.gi +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https  : //tec.sdm.com/pk/mybestshop/git/repository.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:799)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1055)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https: //tec.sdm.com/pk/mybestshop/git/repository.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1723)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1459)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Skipped archiving because build is not successful
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you succeed to pull the repository via `git clone` in command line?

Comment: use the docker jenkins image will solve the issue